# How to content data transformation on a almost equal valued variables?

Tags: r

While doing data transformation on different variables I was unable to transform variables which have higher values and have almost the same range of values. I want to know how to transform this kind of data?.

```
 MonthlyRate    
 Min.   : 2094      
 1st Qu.: 8047      
 Median :14236      
 Mean   :14313      
 3rd Qu.:20462      
 Max.   :26999
```

This is the summary of a variable.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of data transformation are you attempting? Are you trying to bin the data into groups? Normalize it? Something else?

Comment: I am trying to normalize data

Comment: This might help: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/normalized/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to normalize different variables so that they are on the same unitless scale. R has a built-in scale function

```
scale(my_dataframe)
```

which will normalize each column vector so that they have the same range of values, measured in standard deviations from the mean. This only works on numeric vectors, but if your dataframe includes other types of data you can normalize each numeric vector individually

```
my_dataframe$monthly_rate <- scale(my_dataframe$monthly_rate)
```

and acheive the same effect.